# Angular 2 - Bindings cannot contain assignments

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to give a class to a `<tr>` if a property of item has the same value as a property from an object in an array.

Here's the **code** I currently have:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of closingDayGroupsList" [class.inactive]="definitionDetails.Groups.filter(i => i.AbsenceReservationGroupID === item.ID).length > 0">
```

however now I receive the **error**:

```
Bindings cannot contain assignments
```

I'm not sure if what I'm doing is bad practice, or if I'm just making syntax errors.

This is the only way I know to achieve what I want, but it's not working

Comment: Writing logic in Angular expressions is a bad practice. You should create a method in the view's component that will be able to tell whether the groups contain a given ID. The best would probably be if you could cache the results, because the method will be called very frequently.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Its a bad practice to use `expressions` in `angular bindings`

Move the `class` **expression** into controller.

```
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Groups';

    getClass(item): void {

      // add filter logic here
      return this.definitionDetails.Groups.filter(i => i.AbsenceReservationGroupID === item.ID).length > 0

    }
}
```

The tr will be something like,

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of closingDayGroupsList" [class.inactive]="getClass(item)">
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a little problem with that. Take as an example, that I want to stop showing the date to the user which is equal to 0000.00.00, so, by taking the inline expression binding I can find it right to:

```html
 {{(appointment_date === "0000.00.00") ? ' ' : appointment_date}}
```