# Angular Template/Interpolation parse error on find/filter

Tags: html, angular

Error:

> Error: Template parse errors: Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain
> assignments at....
>
> line: `<div>Closed: {{blah}}.find()`...

HTML:

```html
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxLayoutGap="4px">
  <div>Total: {{(issuesData$ | async)?.length}}</div>
  <div>Closed: {{(issuesData$ | async)?.filter(data => {data.closedOn}).length}}</div>
</div>
```

I'm curious if it is possible to use find/filter without running into the template parse error when find/filter are called on a collection in the interpolation statement.

**EDIT:** [Angular 2 - Bindings cannot contain assignments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43117917/angular-2-bindings-cannot-contain-assignments) - This does not work for me because I'm passing in an Observable to the component. OnInit I assign the @Input data variable to the issuesData$ observable. Using something like {{getCount()}} in the interpolation results in no data. I tried implementing that like this:

ANGULAR:

```js
@Input()
data;

ngOnInit() {
  this.issuesData$ = this.data;
  
}

getCount(){
  this.issuesData$.subscribe(data => {
    return data.length;
  })
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div>Total: {{getCount()}}</div>
```

But there is nothing to subscribe to when the `getCount()` is called in the interpolation and this doesn't work either `{{(getCount() | async}}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - Bindings cannot contain assignments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43117917/angular-2-bindings-cannot-contain-assignments)

Comment: @mbojko Please see my edit on the question, thanks.

Comment: Why not use `map` instead? That would be a cleaner way to do this IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In this scenario you should use `map` and format the response in a way that makes the data easily consumable by the component/template.
- Also you can't return a value from `subscribe`, you can assign a value though.
- `find` returns one match, `filter` returns an array. You meant to use `filter` if you are wanting to see the total number of matches using `length`
- If you use `shareReplay` the observable will be resolved once so it can be called multiple times using either `async` pipes or `subscribe` without incurring additional costs if it does something with external resources like making an http request.
- Finally you should define types / definitions, typescript is (can be) strongly typed and this is a big advantage over javascript (what it supersedes).

**Template.html**

```
<div>Total: {{(issuesData$ | async)?.length}}</div>
<div>Closed: {{(issuesData$ | async)?.closedOnLength}}</div>
```

**YourComponent.ts**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Input()
data: Observable<{closedOn:any}[]>;
issuesData$: Observable<{length: number, closedOnLength: number}>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.issuesData$ = this.data.pipe(map((_) => {
    return {
      length: _.length,
      closedOnLength: _.filter(d => d.closedOn).length
    };
  }), shareReplay());
}

count: number;
readCount() {
  // you can't return data in a subscribe callback, it is asynchronous
  // you can assign a value though
  this.issuesData$.subscribe(_ => this.count = _.length);
}
```

Comment: I like your and ConnorsFan's answers. I realized my mistake with the subscribe/return pretty quickly and ended up doing the assignment which ultimately turned into a verbose version of Nothematic's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should subscribe to your Observable and manually assign the variables you want in there instead, purely to reduce the complexity of your template code.

```
@Input()
data;

total: number;
closed: number;

ngOnInit() {
  this.issuesData$ = this.data;
  this.issuesData$.subscribe(next => {
    this.total = next.length;
    this.closed = next.filter(x => x.closedOn).length;
  }
}
```

Then just use the `total` and `closed` variables in your template.

Answer (score 1):

To call `find` or `filter` from the async array in the template, define the callback in the component class. For example, you can set the method `isClosedOn` as the `filter` callback:

```
<div>Closed: {{ (issuesData$ | async)?.filter(isClosedOn).length }}</div>
```

and define it as follows in the component class:

```
public isClosedOn = data => data.closedOn;
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hello-async-pipe-input-qxvuk2?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.