# Using array.prototype.some inside ngIf

Tags: arrays, angular, angular-ng-if, any

I am developing an angular app using the 8th version. Inside the `ngIf` expression, I want to check something existanse inside array. So I have written the expression below:

```
*ngIf="questionniare.factors.some(item => item.intensities.length > 0)"
```

But now I get this error inside the console window:

> Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 34 in
>   [questionniare.factors.some(item => item.intensities.length > 0)]

But as see, I don't have any assignment in my condition. So what's the problem and how can I fix it?

(I know that I can define a method and do this job inside that method, but I want to know if this is a limitation on ngIf that I should consider next times?)

Comment: You can always use pipes for such tasks .Look at this-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43117917/angular-2-bindings-cannot-contain-assignments

Comment: The assignment is certainly made in a hidden for loop to iterate over the array inside de Array.prototye.some function

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error message mentions an "assignment" but the problem is that you are creating an arrow function inside of the component template, which is not allowed. A [feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14129) has been posted on GitHub, asking to support the creation of these functions in Angular templates.

In order to use `Array.prototype.some` in the template, you would have to define the predicate in the component code:

```
// You can define the predicate as a method
public itemHasIntensities(item): boolean {
  return item => item.intensities.length > 0;
}

// You can also define the predicate as an arrow function
public itemHasIntensities = (item): boolean => item.intensities.length > 0;
```

and pass that function as an argument to `Array.prototype.some` in the template:

```
*ngIf="questionniare.factors.some(itemHasIntensities)"
```

[This stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lb4upa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) is similar to your original code and gives the same error. [This other stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jkwvgb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) shows the same example with the callback function defined in the component code.

---

That being said, and as mentioned in the question, the simplest solution is to evaluate the whole condition in a component method:

```
public showElement(): boolean {
  return this.questionniare.factors.some(item => item.intensities.length > 0);
}
```

```
*ngIf="showElement()"
```

Note: memoizing the function would be recommended to avoid performance issues.

Comment: Thanks ConnorsFan. Your attention about arrow function use inside a template was very helpful. Both your and @ElliotMendiola's answer are good enough to be marked as accepted.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that your binding is iterating over the list and tracking a value that is being assigned in the background.

There are a couple solutions to this, first is putting your logic inside a public method on the component class that does this, which is the slower of the two solutions because every time change detection runs it will check your array value.

A better solution is to update a value on the component whenever the array changes

You can do that like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: 'my-component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MyComponent {
  @Input()
  set questionaire(value: Questionaire) {
    this.questionaire$.next(value);
  }

  readonly questionaire$ = new ReplaySubject<Questionaire>(1);
  readonly hasIntensities$ = this.questionaire$.pipe(
    map(questionaire => questionniare.factors.some(item => item.intensities.length > 0))
  );
};
```

Then in the template you can do something like this:
`*ngIf="hasIntensities$ | async"`

You could also accomplish it via change detector ref and ngOnChanges, but this should be the most efficient method

Comment: I'm not sure this is what he ask - he can do a lot of stuff to solve the specific issue - the question is if there is a limitation on using array pure method inside ngIf directive

Comment: He asked `So what's the problem and how can I fix it?` He wasn't specific how he wanted the solution, and I don't see him asking why he cant use an array pure method inside an ngif anywhere

Comment: Thanks @ElliotMendiola and @YochaiAkoka, You both are true. I have first asked `So what's the problem and how can I fix it?` and then `if this is a limitation on ngIf that I should consider next times?`. So all notes and solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This is not written in Angular Documentation but looks like you can't use `Array.some` in structural directives and you should move this logic into specific function inside the compnent.

Comment: So I think I should every time try functions to know if they work or not. This feels awful.