# Access a property of an object by passing the literal of the property from a json

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to access from an html through a variable to the property of an object that has several levels something similar to the following:

Variable named rows

```
[
  {
    name: "Row1",
    levels: {
             name:"name1",
             things: {
                     name: "thing1"
                     }
            }
  },
  {
    name: "Row2",
    levels: {
             name:"name2",
             things: {
                     name: "thing2"
                     }
             }
   }

]
```

Variable named columns

```
[
    {
       id:"col1",
       properties:"name"
    },
    {
       id:"col2",
       properties:"levels.name"
    },
    {
       id:"col1",
       properties:"levels.thing.name"
    }
]
```

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let row of rows ">
      <div *ngFor="let col of columns">
           {{ row[col.properties] }}
      </div>
</div>
```

HTML result

```
Row1
undefined
undefined
Row2
undefined
undefined
```

The problem is that there will not always be the same number of sublevels since it is for a common component, the levels and the organization are passed by the "Columns" variable.

In the previous code the values of the first level are shown, but the The rest is not, it shows them as undefined since it does not access the internal object.

Comment: [Accessing nested JavaScript objects and arrays by string path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6491463)

Comment: How is the `rows` array related to the `columns` array?

Comment: @Pointy In the column array in each object in the properties attribute is the property of the row object that I need to paint

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you very much but I need the solution in HTML and not in javascript

Comment: I'd create a function in the JS file where you pass in the expected path to obtain the value rather than trying to do it directly in your HTML

Comment: https://netbasal.com/introducing-the-new-keyvaluepipe-in-angular-435ac2205c72

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```html
<div *ngFor="let row of rows ">
      <div *ngFor="let col of columns">
           {{ col.properties.split('.').reduce((acc, prop) => acc[prop], row) }}
      </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

[Bindings cannot contain assignments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43118484/11019230).

```html
<div *ngFor="let row of rows ">
      <div *ngFor="let col of columns">
           {{ deepGet(col.properties, row) }}
      </div>
</div>
```

```
// ...
  deepGet(path: string, obj: any): string {
    return path.split('.').reduce((acc, prop) => acc[prop], obj);
  }
// ...
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the answer but when I add that in the code it stops compiling since the error appears Parser Error: Missing expected ) en este ejemplo pasa lo mismo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2yjfwz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: In javascript if I add it in a function if it compiles and behaves properly

Comment: @user22415411 please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43118484/11019230. You have to move it to the component class.